# python: Передача Объектов для дальнейшей их эксплуатации

Tags: python, aiogram, объекты, pyrogram

[python] AIOGRAM & PYROGRAM

Как я мог бы **account** сохранить в:

```
await state.update_data(account=account)
```

```
account = Client(name=f'{phone}', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, in_memory=True)
sc = await account.send_code(phone)
await state.update_data(account =account) # Это вызывает ошибку, как я понял, из за того, что account содержит Объект
await state.update_data(phone=phone)
await state.update_data(phone_code_hash=sc.phone_code_hash)
```

Чтобы в следующем **State()** (**FSM** от **AIOGRAM**) я мог бы достать этот **account** и использовать? (не получается просто так передать его, так как он содержит **Object**)

(хотелось бы передавать с помощью **FSM-технологии**, *это бы мне сохранило много времени*)

Заранее спасибо!